# concatenated matrix multiplication

Tags: performance, numpy, matrix-multiplication

any suggestions for a fast multiply of A * diag(e) * A^T * f for dense matrix A and vectors e, f?

This is what I have now.

```
v[:] = 0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        v[i] = v[i]+A[i,j]*e[j]*np.dot(A[:,j],f)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why not use the numpy dot product? Something like A.dot(diag(e)).dot(A.tranpose()).dot(f)?

Answer (score 2):

Comments by @rubenvb's, where it was suggested to use `A.dot(np.diag(e)).dot(A.transpose()).dot(f)` should make it really fast. But, we don't really need to make it a `2D` array of `diag(e)` there and thus skip one matrix-multiplication. Additionally, we can swap places for `A.T` and `f` and thus avoid the transpose too. Thus, a simplified and much more efficient solution would evolve, like so -

```
A.dot(e*f.dot(A))
```

Here's a quick runtime test on decent sized arrays on all the proposed approaches -

```
In [226]: # Setup inputs
     ...: N = 200
     ...: A = np.random.rand(N,N)
     ...: e = np.random.rand(N,)
     ...: f = np.random.rand(N,)
     ...: 

In [227]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,j,kj,k', A, e, A, f) # @Warren Weckesser's soln
10 loops, best of 3: 77.6 ms per loop

In [228]: %timeit A.dot(np.diag(e)).dot(A.transpose()).dot(f) # @rubenvb's soln
10 loops, best of 3: 18.6 ms per loop

In [229]: %timeit A.dot(e*f.dot(A)) # Proposed here
10000 loops, best of 3: 100 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This should help nicely.

Comment: @Tunneller If either of the posted solutions worked for you, consider accepting the one that best helped. See more here on accepting answers - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion made by @rubenvb is probably the simplest way to do it.  Another way is to use [`einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).

Here's an example.  I'll use the following `a`, `e` and `f`:

```
In [95]: a
Out[95]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [96]: e
Out[96]: array([-1,  2,  3])

In [97]: f
Out[97]: array([5, 4, 1])
```

This is the direct translation of your formula into numpy code.  It is basically the same as @rubenvb's suggestion:

```
In [98]: a.dot(np.diag(e)).dot(a.T).dot(f)
Out[98]: array([ 556, 1132, 1708])
```

Here's the `einsum` version:

```
In [99]: np.einsum('ij,j,jk,k', a, e, a.T, f)
Out[99]: array([ 556, 1132, 1708])
```

You can eliminate the need to transpose `a` by swapping the index labels associated with that argument:

```
In [100]: np.einsum('ij,j,kj,k', a, e, a, f)
Out[100]: array([ 556, 1132, 1708])
```